# How to check 32bit or 64bit Internet Explorer 10 and 11?

Tags: windows, process, operating-system, internet-explorer-11

Before IE10 (likes IE9), I can use `window.navigator.platform` to check IE is 32bit or 64bit.

But for IE10 (IE11), `window.navigator.platform` always returns 32bit.
When I open IE11 from *C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer*, I saw there is a process `IExplorer` and another process `IExplorer*32`.

If one more tab is opened, another process `IExplorer*32` is created.
But it's the same thing when I open IE10 (IE11) from *C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer*.

So, I don't know whether IE10 and IE11 has both 32bit and 64bit. Maybe the parent framework is 64bit, and each tab is 32bit.
Anyone know this?

Comment: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/32024-internet-explorer-11-enable-64-bit-tab-processes-epm.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell whether my IE is 64-bit? (For that matter, Java too?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520948/how-do-i-tell-whether-my-ie-is-64-bit-for-that-matter-java-too)

Comment: Definitely **not** a duplicate, since this is for a later version of IE, with a different default than was on IE 9 and before.

Answer (score 2):

FYI: By default, IE10+'s frame/manager process runs at 64bit, while Desktop Tab processes run in 32bit.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Very helpful. Based on the [How do I tell whether my IE is 64-bit? (For that matter, Java too?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520948/how-do-i-tell-whether-my-ie-is-64-bit-for-that-matter-java-too) question, I first found the iexplore.exe entry in Task Manager. I would not have known to look for the child entries if not for this answer!